# Count occurrences of a column value efficiently in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Car table

```
id   | make   | model
--------
1000 | Toyota | Cammry
1001 | Toyota | Harrier
1002 | Honda  | Accord
1003 | Honda  | Civic
```

I have a Driver table

```
id   | name| car
--------
2000    Finch   1000
2001    Shin    1001
2002    Edward  1003
2003    Qing    1001
2004    Prasad  1002
```

I need write a single SQL query to find out how many drivers are there for each vehicle? (result must have both vehicle make & model and number of drivers)

Comment: "I'm afraid that a subquery will be slow" Why do you think that? You should start by writing code that does the thing you want, and does it correctly, and then worry about how fast it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Car.make, Car.model, COUNT(Driver.id) AS drivers_count
FROM Driver
JOIN Car
ON Driver.car = Car.id
GROUP BY Car.make, Car.model
```

That's a single query. About performance, it looks perfectly fine to me, maybe you could explain us more in depth what's on your mind ?

Comment: [Unknown column 'Car.name' in 'field list'](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3627d7d5847dfdaade6ece56c4a17fab)

Comment: Whoops, you're right

Comment: Now the `make` and `model` are glued together... ([DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f899e2742f5b671ec6655ebc279b3dd4))

Comment: [Operand should contain 1 column(s)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b0588435120e14401492085c7a9757c)

Comment: My problem was resolved. Thank you so much bro

Comment: No worries and @Luuk, thanks for the comments. Should be perfectly fine now.

Comment: You should add Information about indexes and cardinality